# How can I enable the users delete only the objects they create in Django?

Tags: python, django

They can do a bypass for a link by putting the post ID. I do not know how to solve it.

/borrar/id

Template button:

```
{% if user == post.user %}
    <a class="close pull-right" href="{% url 'post_borrar' post.id %}"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>
{% endif %}
```

Template posts/posts_mod_borrar.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el post "{{ object }}"?
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

views.py

```
class PostDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/posts_mod_borrar.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline')
```

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts', blank=True)
    video = models.URLField(blank=True)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    actualizado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-creado"]

def __str__(self):
    return self.texto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check if `obj.user` is the `request.user` in the `dispatch` method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class PostDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    ...

    def user_passes_test(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return self.object.user == request.user
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_passes_test(request):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(PostDeleteView, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If the user doesn't pass `user_passes_test` `PermissionDenied` will be raised

Comment: Thank you for this fast response, its very useful!